# Kivy Application did not stat correctly? Unable to find any valuable Window provider

Tags: python, debugging, kivy, kivy-language

Hi I've have some problems with my kivy. Although everything work fine this evening, now my app didnt run anymore here is ubuntu's log:

```
    [INFO              ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/phucquangho/.kivy/logs/kivy_17-10-02_0.txt
    [INFO              ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.0
    [INFO              ] [Python      ] v3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
    [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
    [INFO              ] [Factory     ] 173 symbols loaded
    [INFO              ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
    [INFO              ] [OSC         ] using <multiprocessing> for socket
    [INFO              ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
    [CRITICAL          ] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider at all!
    egl_rpi - ImportError: cannot import name 'bcm'
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 57, in core_select_lib
        fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_egl_rpi.py", line 12, in <module>
        from kivy.lib.vidcore_lite import bcm, egl

    sdl2 - TypeError: expected bytes, str found
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 65, in core_select_lib
        cls = cls()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 121, in __init__
        super(WindowSDL, self).__init__()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 616, in __init__
        self.create_window()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 171, in create_window
        self.fullscreen, resizable, state)
      File "kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.pyx", line 60, in kivy.core.window._window_sdl2._WindowSDL2Storage.setup_window (kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.c:1447)

    x11 - ImportError: No module named 'kivy.core.window.window_x11'
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 57, in core_select_lib
        fromlist=[modulename], level=0)

    [CRITICAL          ] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
    >>>  Unable to find any valuable Window provider
```

all of others python with kivy app have the same problem, I try to install all over a gain the kivy module but it's not help.

```
here is window's log it's has some different:
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\SPB_Data\.kivy\logs\kivy_17-10-02_0.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5, Jul  8 2017, 04:14:34) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <thread> for socket
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider.
sdl2 - RuntimeError: b'CoCreateInstance() DirectX error 0xx'
  File "D:\PYTHON3.6\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 67, in core_select_lib
    cls = cls()
  File "D:\PYTHON3.6\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 140, in __init__
    super(WindowSDL, self).__init__()
  File "D:\PYTHON3.6\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 899, in __init__
    self.create_window()
  File "D:\PYTHON3.6\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 269, in create_window
    self.fullscreen, resizable, state)
  File "kivy\core\window\_window_sdl2.pyx", line 84, in kivy.core.window._window_sdl2._WindowSDL2Storage.setup_window (kivy\core/window\_window_sdl2.c:2290)
  File "kivy\core\window\_window_sdl2.pyx", line 57, in kivy.core.window._window_sdl2._WindowSDL2Storage.die (kivy\core/window\_window_sdl2.c:1872)

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
 Exception ignored in: 'kivy.properties.dpi2px'
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "D:\PYTHON3.6\lib\site-packages\kivy\utils.py", line 496, in __get__
     retval = self.func(inst)
   File "D:\PYTHON3.6\lib\site-packages\kivy\metrics.py", line 174, in dpi
     EventLoop.ensure_window()
   File "D:\PYTHON3.6\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 127, in ensure_window
     sys.exit(1)
 SystemExit: 1
[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

There'are some different when i run kivy on window and not quite sure what it is about.i tried to do as all the topic on the internet but don't get any good result. So hope there is someone could help me.

Answer (score 0):

did you change your settings (`~/.kivy/config.ini`)? It seems some value passed to the window init is not decoded properly. Which causes the sdl2 init to fail.

Comment: Haven't done anything with it before, I'm fresh to kivy and python so Its hard for me to set something out of my knowledge. But this is just a log when i run my computer with ubuntu, there's a little bit different on window, it had something like systems.exit 1 and so on, I can't post full log on comments so sorry about that, and after a month i've learned kivy the app worked so well.

Comment: just Edit my post so hope you can check it for me thanks a lot

Comment: I saw the edit, but had nothing to add yet (no time to investigate), did you accept the answer just to get my attention? ^^, please don't if it didn't solve your issue. I'll try to get back to you asap :/

Comment: I'm quite new to this site so dont really know the way it work, if there is sth annoying, just tell me

Comment: About the acc I just think it the way to show the thank to your help